# Gitorious - how can I restore repository indexes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ubuntu, gitorious

I am working with `Gitorious` (Ruby+rails on Ubuntu 12.04).

Because I could not log in via WEB recently, I cleared some cache using some rake command.
I am sorry for that I don't remember which command.

After that, I could not push from my local to remote Repositories.
It seems that every Repositories does not work.

ERROR IS LIKE:

```
root@gitclient:~/test# git clone git@gitserver:foo/foo_web.git
Cloning into 'foo_web'...

== Gitorious: ==========================================================

Access denied or wrong repository path

========================================================================
```

Web-app for gitorious is working fine and in gitserver, source code of repositories a still there.

I think something happened to repository indexes.

Could somebody give me a tip how to debug or fix it ?

updated:

SSH access with public key works

```
root@gitclient:~# ssh git@gitserver
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome, userfoo. Use git to push/pull your repositories
Connection to gitserver closed.
root@gitclient:~#
```

Server side git clone from FILE SYSTEM works

```
root@gitserver:~/test# git clone file://localhost//repositories/foo/bar_src.git
Cloning into 'bar_src'...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in apache web server setting.

Because I am running a few web apps, I configure like followed.

## /config/gitorious.yml

```
...
gitorious_host: git.mydomain.com
...
```

## apache virtual host

```
root@gitserver:~ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gitorious
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias git.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/gitorious/public

    Redirect permanent / https://git.mydomain.com/
    #Redirect permanent / https://git.mydomain.com/ # if I comment this line, works fine
</VirtualHost>
```

It seems like that when client access git-server with git command, Apache web server is intercepting it.

Like another posts said, **sub domain** or **web server** setting is problem.